# SQL query to find comparision between different products

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i am a newbie to SQL and have one doubt on comparing different products across multiple tables.
I have 3 tables

T1:
Product_type
order_id

T2 and T3 also has the same fields.

All the tables have different product types. They may or may not have same order ids. Its like you can order product p1 from T1 and product p2 from T2 together on the same order id o1 or they can be separate orders.

I want to find the number of orders where product type(p1) from T1 and product type(p2) from T2 are ordered in the same order(having the same order id).

I am trying to run the query like this :

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) as CountOf from
(
    select product_type from t1
    UNION ALL select product_type from t2
)
AS m
where t1.product_type = p1 and t2.product_type = p2;
```

What i figured out is that i cannot access t1 and t2 in the outer query since they are used in the inner query. So is there a way i can make comparision between products?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    count(distinct t1.order_id) as OrderCount
from
    t1
    inner join
    t2 on t1.order_id = t2.order_id
where
    t1.product_type = 'p1' and
    t2.product_type = 'p2'
```

Comment: Hi, i tried but it says the order_id is ambiguous. No idea on what is means.

Comment: forgot to qualify the table name, try it now

Comment: it works now. Thank you. I had only one doubt. Is there a way we can do that for multiple orders in a single query. Or i need to run different join statements for different tables and products?

Comment: This will count all orders that contain product_type p1 from table 1 and product_type p2 from table 2.  If you need to have a count for different product types and/or different tables, then the query would need to be adjusted.  If you just need different product_type combinations, those can be changed in the where clause.

Comment: Yes i figured it out. Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what you want.
But inner query scope to brackets only. So you can not access outside to brackets. try to this

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT order_id) as CountOf from
(
    select DISTINCT order_id from t1
    where t1.product_type = p1
    UNION ALL 
    select DISTINCT order_id from t2
    where t2.product_type = p2
) m
```

Comment: This won't return a count where p1 and p2 were ordered on the same order_id.  That appears to be what they are asking...

Comment: Hi, yes i want to find out the number of orders where p1 and p2 were ordered together.